# Data type mismatch

Tags: c#

I got this error when I tried to select userid from a database to datatable. The first userid is an autonumber, the second USERID is a number, and the database is a MS Access DB.

```
private void ()
{
    OdbcDataAdapter ad = new OdbcDataAdapter("select userid from userinfo where BadgeNumber='" + UserID + "'", this.FM.Cn);
    DataTable t = new DataTable();
    ad.Fill(t);
    ad.Dispose();
    if (t.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand();
        cmd.Connection = this.FM.Cn;

        string id = t.Rows[0][0].ToString();
        //Check Date
        OdbcDataAdapter add = new OdbcDataAdapter("Select USERID from checkinout where Userid='" + id + "'", this.FM.Cn);
        DataTable tc = new DataTable();
        add.Fill(tc); // <- I gotta error here.
        add.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try removing the single quotes: `Userid=" + id + "`

Comment: Just as you enclose string literals in double quotes in C# but you don't do the same for numbers, so you enclose string literals in single quotes in SQL but you don't do the same for numbers.  Also, you should avoid concatenating literals at all and look into using parameterised queries.

Comment: @HanletEscaño, yes, you are right.

Comment: Thank u. Hanlet Escano. it worked.
Could you explain me about it?

Comment: ok... understand... thank you jmcilhinney.

Comment: @jmcilhinney or Hanlet please make this into an answer so we can close this question - thanks

Comment: try to use paramterized queries to avoid such errors.

Comment: I'll let @HanletEscaño do that, given that his comment is a direct answer to the question and was also posted before mine.

Comment: @jmcilhinney - respect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query to:

```
"Select USERID from checkinout where Userid=" + id
```

In SQL queries, strings literals (or chars) are required to be enclosed within a pair of single quotes `'`, which are used to delimiter the string. A delimiter is pretty much a character used to identify boundaries - in the case of a string, the single quotes specify where the string starts and where it ends.

Because of the nature of numbers (integers for example), it is not necessary to indicate a delimiter such as single quotes. Your code was failing because when the [database engine](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4603/what-exactly-is-a-database-engine) saw the single quotes, it was expecting a string, but your column was a number datatype, and this is why you obtained a *Data type mismatch* error when executing your query.